# Lagged Fibonnaci Algorthm

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, generator

im having this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object when i try to call any method, in this case i tried calling the Next method.

As for code in my LaggedFibonnaci class i have:

```
    int[] initialsetofvalues;
    int j = 30;
    int k = 127;
    int m = 2 ^ 31;
    int n;

    public LaggedFibonnaci()
    {
        int[] initialsetofvalues = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    }

    public int Next(int maxValue)
    {
        n = k;
        int randNo = (initialsetofvalues[n - j] + initialsetofvalues[n - k]) % m;
        n++;
        return randNo % (maxValue + 1);
    }


    public int NextWithDiscarding(int maxValue)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        //Generate 127 Random Numbers
        for (int i = maxValue - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int randNumbers = rand.Next(1, 128);
            randNumbers = initialsetofvalues[maxValue];
        }


        //Generate 997 Random Numbers
        for (int i = maxValue - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int randNumbers = rand.Next(1, 998);
            randNumbers = initialsetofvalues[maxValue];
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(rand);

    }

    public int NextWithRandomShuffling(int maxValue)
    {
        int[] v = new int[61];

        for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++)
        {
            v[i] = Next(maxValue);
        }

        int y = Next(maxValue);
        int rand = (61 * y) / m;
        v[rand] = y;
        return y;

    }
}
```

I also implemented a maxValue from the interface IRandomProvider, and the code is:

```
public interface IRandomProvider
    {
        int Next(int maxValue);
    }
```

and yes, the laggedfibonnaci class is inheriting from this interface.

Program Code:

```
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LaggedFibonnaci lfn = new LaggedFibonnaci();
            int[] initialsetofvalues = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

           int array = lfn.Next(2);

            Console.WriteLine(array);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
```

Any Help? Thanks

Comment: (So your class does have source code. Pity it doesn't include hints to its purpose.)

Comment: Meaning? all im trying to do is do a laggedfibonnaci algorithm, how is that not a hint?

Comment: This question would be significantly better if you did one of two things. The better option would be to narrow down the problem to as small a portion of your code as possible (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). The other option would be to at least include a full piece of code that can compile and run so that we can see what is actually going on, and not just chunks of code without context

Comment: Sorry im still new to this, thanks for the remarks tho!

Answer (score 1):

Change the constructor:

```
public LaggedFibonnaci()
{
    this.initialsetofvalues = new[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
}
```

You created a local list instead of an instance list.

Comment: I adjusted the code in my answer. After fixing this you'll find that there are more errors in your code.

Comment: its popping the same error as before tho, how is that a solution?

Comment: Did you change the constructor or did you change the main method? I tested your code with my fix and it doesn't show the same error.

Comment: it gives me  Index was outside the bounds of the array now.

Comment: Am i not declaring 10 elements in the array?

Comment: Yes, there are more issues with the code. This web site is not here to help you debug but instead to answer clear questions.

Comment: you are justifying to spam the website with a new question every time?

Comment: all i'm doing is trying to get this to work mate, if you're such a smarty pants  it shouldn't be so difficult to help me find a solution to this error :)

Comment: This is not about me being a 'smarty pants' (let's not get into personal arguments) this is about what this site is for and is not for. SO is not a personal debugging service. It is a place to ask a well stated questions and only asking a single question per post to make the questions as valuable as possible for the rest of the internet.

Comment: very nice answer then mr erno de weerd, you created a new problem for me cheers for your help! :)

Comment: @LukeCassar You asked a question (and not a very good one at that) and Erno de Weerd was nice enough to parse through your issue and find the solution. It isn't his fault that your code has other problems, and it isn't the purpose of this site to take your broken code and fix it for you. If you don't like that then go find a forum that is willing to do what you want, but don't come here and complain about the entire point of SO

Comment: yes emo de weerd was very nice to try and help, and i did not come here to seek people into solving all my problems, i came here seeking help so that i can understand and learn, from other experienced programmers. I am still very new to algorithms.. So who im here to learn to seek people to do my work.